# Reverse object hierarchy

Tags: javascript

is there any way to reverse the object in js?

wanna make a function, but struggling hard.
I tried to find the object depth-first and then make a founded amount of iterations for .. in .. inside the object but don't know how to rewrite the new one

```js
const initObject = { 
  value: 5,
  next: {
   value: 10,
   next: {
     value: 15
     next: null
   }
  },
}

//expected result

const newObject = {
  value: 15,
  next: {
    value: 10,
    next: {
      value: 5,
      next: null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, don't use `for … in` to enumerate arbitrary properties. This structure specifically represents a list which you need to iterate by following `.next` pointers. (And only lists are reversible, arbitrarily nested objects are not).

Comment: If you have troubles with iteration, consider a recursive approach instead. (You'll need an accumulator parameter though)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a recursive function to collect all the values. Then use `reduce` to create a nested object from the values:

```js
const initObject = { 
  value: 5,
  next: {
   value: 10,
   next: {
     value: 15,
     next: null
   }
  }
}

const getValues = ({ value, next }) =>
  next 
    ? [value, ...getValues(next)] 
    : [value]

const createObject = values => 
  values.reduce((next, value) => ({ value, next }), null)

const output = createObject(getValues(initObject))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let newObject = null;

for(let o = initObject; o; o = o.next) {
    newObject = { value: o.value, next: newObject };
}
```

What this is doing is looping the `initialObject` from the outer layer inwards (using the `next` property to go from layer to layer until we reach `null`) while constructing the `newObject` from the inside outwards (each constructed layer will use the previous layer, stored as the current value of `newObject`, as the `next` property, hence the initial value of `newObject` is `null`), like so:

[image]

**Note:** As pointed out by @jperl in a comment bellow, if the objects have multiple properties (not just `value`), then simply use a [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to include them all in `newObject` by replacing:

```
newObject = { value: o.value, next: newObject };
```

with:

```
newObject = { ...o, next: newObject };
```

**Demo:**

```js
const initObject = { value: 5, next: { value: 10, next: { value: 15, next: null } } };

let newObject = null;

for(let o = initObject; o; o = o.next) {
    newObject = { value: o.value, next: newObject };
}

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: This is great! (And the visualization is neat too. How did you create it?)

Comment: @adiga thanks. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), 3 layers exported as an animated .gif with 1 second delay between them.

Comment: Pretty neat. Or ```for(let o = initObject; o; o = o.next) {
    newObject = { ...o, next: newObject };
}``` in case we have several props.

Comment: @jperl Good point. I've added it as a note. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function which does the job, the process is:

- Build an array of the `value` values
- Reverse the array (using `Array.reverse`)
- Rebuild your object structure with the reversed array values

```
const reverseObject = (object) => {
  const values = [];
  let currentObject = object;
  while (currentObject && currentObject.value) {
    values.push(currentObject.value);
    currentObject = currentObject.next;
  }
  const reversedValues = values.reverse();
  const newObject = {};
  let currentNewObject = newObject;
  for (let i = 0; i < reversedValues.length; i++) {
    currentNewObject.value = reversedValues[i];
    currentNewObject.next = null;
    if (i < reversedValues.length - 1) {
      currentNewObject = currentNewObject.next = {};
    }
  }
  return newObject;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As Bergi already mentioned in the comments, this can be done using recursion. It is even very concise and readable if you do it as follows.
It iterates through each (nested) node and builds up an inverted object using the `nextAccumulator` variable.

```js
function invert({value, next}, nextAccumulator = null) {
    const node = {value, next: nextAccumulator};
    return next ? invert(next, node) : node;
}

const inverted = invert({
    value: 5,
    next: {
        value: 10,
        next: {
            value: 15,
            next: null,
        },
    },
});

console.log(inverted);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a single function approach with a second paramter for collecting the objects.

```js
const
    reverse = ({ value, next: sub }, next = null) => sub
        ? reverse(sub, { value, next })
        : { value, next },
    object = { value: 5, next: { value: 10, next: { value: 15, next: null } } },
    result = reverse(object);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as mine.

Comment: Or rather two duplicate answers.

Comment: or just a simplified duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706836/flip-key-value-pair-on-1-lvl-depth

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create a function to get all the values in form of array in order
- reverse the array
- convert that array back to object using recursion

```js
const newObject = {
  value: 15,
  next: {
    value: 10,
    next: {
      value: 5,
      next: null
    }
  }
}

function reverse(obj){
  let values = [];
  values.reverse();
  function getValue(tempObj){
    values.push(tempObj.value);
    if(tempObj.next){
      getValue(tempObj.next);
    }
  }
  getValue(obj)
  const ob = {};
  let  i = 0;
  function reassignValue(tempObj){
    if(i >= values.length){
      console.log(i)
      return;
    }
    tempObj.value = values[i];
    tempObj.next = {};
    i++;
    reassignValue(tempObj.next);
    
    
    
  }
  reassignValue(ob);
  return ob
}
console.log(reverse(newObject))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a linked list. You'll easily find a reverse LinkedList algorithm on the Internet.

Note that I don't need to convert anything.

Typescript

```
type LinkedList = {
  value: number,
  next: LinkedList
} | null

const list: LinkedList = {
  value: 5,
  next: {
    value: 10,
    next: {
      value: 15,
      next: null
    }
  },
}

const reverseLinkedList = (list: LinkedList) => {
  let prev = null;
  let current = list
  let next = null
  while (current != null) {
    next = current.next
    current.next = prev
    prev = current
    current = next
  }
  list = prev
  return list
}



console.log(reverseLinkedList(list))
```

Javascript

```js
const list = {
  value: 5,
  next: {
    value: 10,
    next: {
      value: 15,
      next: null
    }
  },
}

const reverseLinkedList = (list) => {
  let prev = null;
  let current = list
  let next = null
  while (current != null) {
    next = current.next
    current.next = prev
    prev = current
    current = next
  }
  list = prev
  return list
}



console.log(reverseLinkedList(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```js
let initObject={value:5,next:{value:10,next:{value:15,next:null}}};

let flip = (obj,nexts=[]) =>{
    nexts.push(obj.value);
    if (obj.next){
        flip(obj.next,nexts)
    }
    obj.value = nexts.shift()
    return obj;
}

let result = flip(initObject)
console.log(result);
let original = flip(result)
console.log(original)
```